# Best way to "shift negative byte" in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, byte, bit-shift, shift

When I try to right-shift a negative byte, I realized it's converted to int before the shifting is carried out.

```
byte bVar = (byte)-1;
System.out.println(bVar >>> 1);// this prints 2147483647
```

But I want to "shift negative byte" as if zeros are appended to the significant side.

Currently I'm doing it like this. 127 is the result I desire.

```
System.out.println((bVar & 0xFF) >>> 1);// this prints 127
```

But this doesn't look very straightforward. It involves 3 steps (a conversion and 2 operators).

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Not really, no. However you shouldn't care about the involvement of 3 steps. Your CPU can handle billions of instructions per second.

Comment: i guess it happens because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension, not sure if it's possible to do in shorter amount of steps

Comment: Your solution doesn't look complicated to me.

Comment: Probably won't be compiled to a sign-extension followed by an AND by the JIT compiler, unless it is dumb.